# Where do I put the entrypoint.sh file Rails App for Docker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/ruby-on-rails-developer-series-creating-a-docker-container-around-your-application) and also official [Docker](https://docs.docker.com/samples/rails/) and they all reference an entrypoint.sh file with the contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
# Remove a potentially pre-existing server.pid for Rails.
rm -f /myapp/tmp/pids/server.pid
# Then exec the container's main process (what's set as CMD in the Dockerfile).
exec "$@"
```

Do I need to create a folder `usr/bin/` as referenced in the dockerfile below or `/bin/bash` as the comment in the entrypoint.sh file above states and place it in my root directory? I'm a bit surprised I couldn't find any details on it.

Everyone clearly states that the Dockerfile should be placed in the root directory.

```
# Dockerfile
FROM ruby:3.0.0
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y postgresql-client
WORKDIR /app
COPY Gemfile Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install

# Add a script to be executed every time the container starts.
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 3000

# Configure the main process to run when running the image
CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

Of course when I run `docker build -t rails-docker .` I get the error

```
 => ERROR [7/8] COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/                                                                       0.0s
------
 > [7/8] COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/:
------
failed to compute cache key: "/entrypoint.sh" not found: not found
```

---

**Edit**

Project Structure

```
> AppName
  > app
  > bin
  > config
  > db
  > lib
  > log
  > public
  > storage
  > test
  > tmp
  > vendor
- .gitfiles
- config.ru
- Dockerfile
- Gemfile
- Gemfile.lock
- Rakefile
```

Comment: How does your folder structure look like? It seems that it fails when copying `entrypoint.sh` and not when executing it.

Comment: I actually don't still have it. Or where is it copied from? Referencing just how the Gemfile is copied. I will also update the project structure now

Comment: Everything is relative to the context you specify when you build the image. In your case, it's `.` a.k.a. current directory. That means that when you say `COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/bin`, Docker expects `entrypoint.sh` file in the same level as `Dockerfile`. If that's not the case for you, try fixing that.

Comment: Ah, placing the `entrypoint.sh` file at the same level as `Dockerfile` worked. I also didn't understand the `COPY` command: 'Oringin -> Destination` and here `Destination` is a folder managed by Docker or in Docker. Thank you

Comment: You can make this the answer

Comment: Destination is the folder inside the container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the error message, the problem is not when executing `entrypoint.sh` script, but when copying it. Your script is not where Docker is expecting it, or in other words, not where you told Docker it should be.

When you build image with `docker image build -t <image_name> .`, you're telling Docker that `Dockerfile` is in the current directory (`.`) and that the *build context* for the image is the current directory. That means that when you use `COPY <src> <dst>`, the `<src>` (or the source file) is relative to the build context, and the `<dst>` is a path inside Docker container. So, when you say `COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/bin`, Docker is expecting `entrypoint.sh` script to be located in the current directory - `.` from `docker image build` command.